# The real numbers as a completion of the rationals

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The real numbers are the completion (i.e. Cauchy sequences modulo equivalence) of the rational numbers.  I want to define the real numbers this way, but without using uniform spaces.  The problem is that most definitions I see of metric spaces stipulate that the distance is a function to the real numbers, making this definition circular.

My question is: can we loosen the definition of metric spaces and still retain all (or most) of what we know about metric spaces?  e.g. allow the distance function to be a map
$$d: X \rightarrow k$$
where $k$ is any totally ordered field?  or $k = \mathbb{Q}$?  Is there some sense in which every totally ordered field "contains" $\mathbb{Q}$?

One issue that comes to mind is that one can't really talk about "distance preserving morphisms" anymore without fixing $k$.

Comment: Certainly every totally ordered field contains (a copy of) $\mathbb{Q}$. And the definition of the reals via equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences is not circular.

Comment: Why is this true?  And is it a canonical copy of $\mathbb{Q}$?  My ignorance in this subject is near total.

Comment: It seems circular to me if you use the real numbers to define the distance function, which is necessary to define Cauchy sequences, unless there's some subtle logic thing going on.

Comment: Yes, it is canonical.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence of rationals is a sequence $(a_i)$ of rationals such that for any (rational) $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that if $m,n\ge N$ then $|a_m-a_n|\lt \epsilon$. We have not stepped outside the rationals. No general distance function involved.

Comment: The real numbers can also be constructed as the Dedekind completion (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dedekind+completion) of the rationals. This is a purely order-theoretic construction and requires no notion of generalized metric or uniform structure; you don't even need the ability to subtract.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uniform spaces are your friends.
2. Basically, as André Nicolas commented, you can take $k=\Bbb Q$ first to define the 'metric' whose completion is $\Bbb R$.
3. So, yes, it does make sense to consider metrics $X\times X\to k$ with any totally ordered field, moreover $k$ might also be any totally ordered Abelian (semi-)group.
4. $\Bbb Q$ is present in any field of characteristic $0$, as the subfield generated by $1$.